# Create tooltip message when mouse over on radio button in radio button group

Tags: wicket

Wicket frame work: I have radio button group displaying radio button and labels. 
Requirement: when mouse move over to 2nd radio button or 3 rd button only I have to display tool tip message on top of the corresponding radio button item.

Could anyone please tell me how to do it in wicket frame work?

Answer (score 1):

take a look at RadioChoice component (http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.0.x/index.html?org/apache/wicket/markup/html/form/RadioGroup.html). You can override method getAdditionalAttributes to provide extra attribute 'title' for radio button tag . 
You can also use getAdditionalAttributesForLabel to add this attribute to the label of the button.

Comment: sorry, getAdditionalAttributesForLabel is available also for Wicket 6

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `AttributeModifier` behavior to the `Radio`s you want.

```
Radio radio1 = new Radio("1", new Model(1));
radio1.add(AttributeModifier.replace("title", Model.of("The tooltip")));
```